# Unlimited Knapsack Problem

Tags: knapsack-problems

How would I solve the unbounded knapsack problem, only this time aiming to maximize the weight instead of the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way is to consider the value of each pack as $cost(object)=weight(object)$ (Now every object has a uniform value) and solve the same knapsack problem. The other way is to consider a variation of packing problems [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems)